# How to filter swift ForEach List

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

i want to make two lists feom my array of inputed data.

```
struct Users: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let name: String
    let age: String
    let country: String
    let gender: String
}
```

//i would like to get a list that only shows the male users, and another list for female, when //i use the code bellow, the both list updates but the male user apears on male list and on the //female list a section is created but blank

```
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(Users) { user in
                    if user.gernder == "Male" {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(user.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(user.age)
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
                
            } header: {
                Text("Male users")
            }
            Section {
                ForEach(Users) { user in
                   if user.gernder == "Female" {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(user.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(user.age)
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
                
            } header: {
                Text("Female users")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created similar code which works (see below). Therefore, I believe you may have some typos/errors in your code:

"gernder" does not seem to be correct:

```
if user.gernder == "Male"
```

I am not sure that "Users" is a variable of type [Users] in the line below:

```
  ForEach(Users) { user in
```

Below is code that works for me:

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let name: String
    let gender: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let users : [User] = [
        User(name: "John", gender: "Male"),
        User(name: "Marie", gender: "Female"),
        User(name: "Patrick", gender: "Male"),
        User(name: "Josephine", gender: "Female")
        
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    if user.gender == "Male" {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(user.name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            } header: {
                Text("Male users")
            }
            Section {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    if user.gender == "Female" {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(user.name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            } header: {
                Text("Female users")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works to a degree, but it doesn't fully address the initial problem where one of the components was to provide `.onDelete()` capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to arrange your data in a correct nested way. This means you need to add a parent, where it shows the one to many relationship between male users and female users. Otherwise, you can use the similar approach.

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let gender: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let users : [User] = [
        User(name: "John", gender: "Male"),
        User(name: "Marie", gender: "Female"),
        User(name: "Patrick", gender: "Male"),
        User(name: "Josephine", gender: "Female")
    ]
    
    private func usersByGender(_ gender: String) -> [User] {
        users.filter { $0.gender == gender }
    }
    
    private func deleteUser(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
        
        indexSet.forEach { index in
            print(index)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            Section {
                ForEach(usersByGender("Male")) { user in
                    Text(user.name)
                }.onDelete { indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        let userToDelete = usersByGender("Male")[index]
                    }
                }
            } header: {
                Text("Male")
            }
            
            Section {
                ForEach(usersByGender("Female")) { user in
                    Text(user.name)
                }.onDelete { indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        let userToDelete = usersByGender("Female")[index]
                    }
                }
            } header: {
                Text("Female")
            }


        }
    }
}
```